# How to change angular fxLayout (row to column) regarding if else statement

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-flex-layout

https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs

How I can set direction regard to some value

```
<div if(value) fxLayout='row' else fxLayout='column'>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just think this is sufficient for answer your question:

1. Code in component:`this.anyVal = true; // use any logic here to set this value`
2. Element in template: `<div fxLayout="{{anyVal ? 'column' : 'row'}}">`

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to use a different layout on a responsive beaviour, then you only need to use the flex layout breakpoints such as fxLayout.sm="column".

Here is the full list of the available breakpoints https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Responsive-API#mediaqueries-and-aliases

So, your tag should look like this:

```
<div fxLayout="row"
     fxLayout.sm="column" >...</div>
```

If you need it, you can use more than one breakpoint:

```
<div fxLayout="row"
     fxLayout.xs="column"
     fxLayout.sm="column" 
     fxLayout.md="column">...</div>
```

If you want to learn more about the flex layout in angular besides de official documentation you can check this great tutorial: https://alligator.io/angular/flex-layout/

Hope this works!

Happy coding!